# Daffodil Bulbs Planting in Winter

Tags: planting, bulbs, daffodils

January 29, Zone 5

I optimistically purchased 500 daffodil bulbs late last fall and did not get them in the ground before winter. I stored them outside in the container they came in, like a milk crate but lower and they were stacked about 2-3 high. I put the container on a wire chair and covered the top only with a tarp. I did this with the tulip bulbs also. They did not get wet at all.

The tulip bulbs were very firm and I think they will bloom later but will be fine. They were very hard and healthy.

The daffodil bulbs seem a little soft, but not totally squishy. I am wondering what the odds of these blooming and being healthy next year might be, and was looking for opinions.

I haven't planted daffodils much so don't know if this is normal or not.

Also, any advice on extra things I can do to make the best of this situation and baby the bulbs/plants would be appreciated.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean by a little soft? Do they rot or are they drying out? Do you have pictures?

Like you probably know, it's too late to plant them now. My tulips and daffodils are 5-10 cm above ground already (Netherlands, zone 8b, 30 January).

The way I store these bulbs is in cardboard box. Between every layer of bulbs I put some old newspapers to separate the layers. The box is best kept in a cellar or garage (cool, dry place). I think outside the temperatures can become too extreme (freezing cold or too hot in summer).

Comment: Cindy R. Check all your bulbs and throw out the soft ones. Bulbs should be firm. Bring them in and put in garage or cellar as b. nota pointed out. Maybe some will survive, if not, send away for 50 more. Remember planting for spring should be done in the fall, Oct. preferably. Good Luck.